# Is possible to save Realm documentation for offline reading?

Tags: android, ios, realm

I'm going to vacations this Saturday and I need to have Realm API documentation available for offline reading (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/index.html). Does it exist somewhere for download? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the top of the webpage that you linked it says: Install in Dash.

Dash is an app in App Store:

https://itunes.apple.com/ro/app/dash-api-docs-snippets/id458034879?mt=12

that let's you view documentation offline.

Comment: Thank you. Every time I clicked on it my AppStore app returned error so I dint know what it is and google didnt gave me any useful result. Thanks again

Comment: The "Install in Dash" link is broken. Docset can't be incorporated into Dash -  running it on OSX El Capitan